# return false not working in jquery require field validation

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdownlist (.color) to validate with jquery.Default value of this dropdown is **VÆLG**.And I want to validate this in an anchor tag click (.viewmore).my code is like this

```
     $(".viewmore").on('click',function(event){
      requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color"));

      });


         function requiredValidation(ddl) {

    ddl = $(ddl);

    var isValid = true;
    if (jQuery.trim(ddl.val()) == 'VÆLG' ) {
        isValid = false;
        ddl.addClass("error");

    }
    else {
        ddl.removeClass("error");
    }
   alert(isValid)
    return isValid;
}
```

at last alert message I am getting the value **false** correctly.but still the page redirect to given url of the anchor tag.can any one tell me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
return requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick method isn't returning true or false. Try this:

```
 $(".viewmore").on('click',function(event){
      return requiredValidation($(this).parents('.box01').find(".color"));

  });
```